# R Plot over London

Tags: r, plot, rworldmap

I have some data I want to draw over the London map.

But whenever I try to run following code:

```
library("Hmisc")
library("lubridate")
library("maptools")
require("rworldmap")

mtl <- readShapePoly('borough/London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp')

data = read.csv("test.csv")
data = data[,c("Accident_Index","Longitude","Latitude","Date")]

data$Date <- as.character(data$Date)
data$Date <- gsub(' ', '', data$Date)
data$Date <- dmy(data$Date, tz='UTC')

start <- (dmy("01/01/2011", tz='UTC'))
days <- start

# pre processed matrix for incidents
# trust me you don't want to calculate
# this from scratch (Takes hours)
load('time_mat.Rdata')

# plot initial world map
plot(getMap())

da <- 1

# where the plots will be outputted
png(paste('plots/',days[da],'.png',sep=''), height=800, width=1200, bg='grey')

# plot london map
plot(mtl,col='darkgrey')
text(51.5072, 0.1275,paste("Collisions in London\n",days[da]),cex=2)

points(data$Longitude,data$Latitude, pch=20, col='white', cex=2)

par(lwd=2.5,cex=1.4)

subplot(
  plot(days[1:da],incident_rate[1:da],
    lwd=1.5,type='l',
    ylab='', xlab='',
    col='red',
    ylim=c(0,max(c(1,max(incident_rate[1:da]))))
  ),  
  size=c(5.5,2), 51.5072, -0.1275, vadj=0,hadj=0
)

dev.off()
```

> Error in par(plt = c(xy$x, xy$y), new = TRUE) : 
>     invalid value specified for graphical parameter "plt"

**EDIT 2:** Re-factored and reduced the code.

Zipped up the entire code folder, and dependent data for ease of deployment/testing, ended up being ~17mb compressed (due to the shapefiles):

[Megafileupload link](http://www.megafileupload.com/qQbR/test.zip)

Comment: Anyone? I am seriously stuck on this :/

Comment: Can you provide data to make your code reproducible?

Comment: I have changed the code above to full code, and also included the datasets used and instructions on the shapefile.

Comment: Okay, reproducible now but it's a lot. Can you narrow your code (and maybe your data) down a bit to illustrate the problem *minimally*? Do you need the for loop to get the error, or if you delete the for loop and set `da <- 1`? Or is iteration the problem, does `for (da in 1:2)` show the problem? Is the line `print(days[da])` necessary? Please make a **minimal** example - see how much of this code you can delete and still demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hello Gregor, I have reduced the code by a whole lot (the error still being re-producible) and in addition also included a compressed zip file of the entire directory.

Comment: The error is thrown at the subplot bit. Perhaps due to Longitude/Latitude being misread? I see nothing wrong with the snippet of code. Maybe the error is caused before, but only thrown at when trying to use subplot.